# Numpy to solve multi-variable algebraic function

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume we know the following:

```
a = 1
b = 4
c = 7
d = 2
e = 2
f = 9
```

With these six variables, we can solve for `X`, `Y`, and `Z` as follows:

```
X = (b - a) / (d + e)
Y = 2 * np.sin(X/2) * ((c / X) + f)
Z = 2 * np.sin(X/2) * ((a / X) + d)

print(X)
print(Y)
print(Z)
0.75
13.42999273315508
2.4418168605736503
```

Now, let's flip things around and assume that we're **given** the values of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, ***as well as*** `d`, `e`, and `f`.

How would we solve for the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`?  My algebra is shaky.  Is this something that Numpy can handle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Numpy, no. (Or rather, not as easily, or accurately.)

Sympy, yes.

Declare `a`, `b` and `c` as symbols.
Create expressions that should equal to zero (by moving the left hand side of the equation to the right hand side and changing the sign).
Use `sympy.sin` instead of `math.sin` or `np.sin`.
Use `sympy.solve` to get the solution of the system.

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import a, b, c

X = 0.75
Y = 13.42999273315508
Z = 2.4418168605736503
d = 2
e = 2
f = 9

e1 = (b - a) / (d + e) - X
e2 = 2 * sympy.sin(X/2) * ((c / X) + f) - Y
e3 = 2 * sympy.sin(X/2) * ((a / X) + d) - Z

sympy.solve([e1, e2, e3])
# => {a: 1.00000000000000, b: 4.00000000000000, c: 7.00000000000000}
```

Comment: Amadan and Bill -- thank you for your help.  Thinking about this further, is this something that might be solved with `np.linalg.solve`?  Perhaps by transforming this problem into a system of linear equations?

Comment: I wasn't paying too much attention to the equations themselves to see if they are linear (or can be transformed into a system of linear equations). You need to math it out. Sympy does symbolic algebra for you, and is not restricted to linear systems. (Since `X` is a float and not a symbol, I could have used `math.sin`. But again, sympy lets me not worry about it.)

Comment: Yes, they are linear.  Since they are, is it possible to use Numpy to solve this?

Comment: I answered already. If you have a system of linear equations, you can use `np.linarg.solve`. But it is your responsibility to transform the equations into the matrices that it needs. Thus to answer that is more a matter of mathematics than programming.

Answer (score 3):

Solving equations with unknown variables can be done in Sympy.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, Eq, sin

a, b, c, d, e, f, X, Y, Z = symbols("a b c d e f X Y Z")

eqns = [
    Eq(X, (b - a) / (d + e)),
    Eq(Y, 2 * sin(X / 2) * ((c / X) + f)),
    Eq(Z, 2 * sin(X / 2) * ((a / X) + d)),
]
assignments = {a: 1, b: 4, c: 7, d: 2, e: 2, f: 9}

print(solve([eq.subs(assignments) for eq in eqns], [X, Y, Z]))
```

Output:

```
[(3/4, 110*sin(3/8)/3, 20*sin(3/8)/3)]
```

To solve for a, b, c just replace X, Y, Z in solve and add their values in the assignments dict.